# Rest API (advanced or pro account)

Tags: php, paypal

I'm working with PHP language.
I would like to build a form and execute direct payment with credit card on my site.
So I download the php sdk library from paypal official repo : https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php

For the time, I create a developer account and a sandbox environment. In my sandbox, I use a "business" account to test my app and everything work fine with REST API.

I don't know if a paypal advanced account will be enough to achieve this feature in using REST when I'll go in production mode.
Do you know if I absolutely have to create a pro account ? I'm little confused.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **US accounts** **if you use REST API** for accepting the credit cards there is no need for any Pro and Advanced account . You just need to have a Business Verified account . You can check the more information here:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/#direct-credit-card-payments